# What are the different secrets in the SSLKEYLOGFILE file?

Tags: tls

I've dumped the secrets from a TLS handshake into a text file but I don't understand what the different secrets are. I have:

SERVER_HANDSHAKE_TRAFFIC_SECRET
EXPORTER_SECRET
SERVER_TRAFFIC_SECRET_0
CLIENT_HANDSHAKE_TRAFFIC_SECRET
CLIENT_TRAFFIC_SECRET_0

HANDSHAKE_TRAFFIC_SECRET I guess is the Diffie-Hellman Secret? I have no idea what the others are, because I thought that the traffic secrets would need to be the same if they're used to the symmetric key for AES or CHACHA20? Do the server and client both send each other data encrypted symmetrically but with a different key depending on the sender?

I've been partly to use this as a guide because I find the RFC8446 document quite hard to learn from: https://tls13.ulfheim.net/ .

Comment: The format is documented [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Projects/NSS/Key_Log_Format). Names like `SERVER_HANDSHAKE_TRAFFIC_SECRET` reflect the names in the RFC, see for example [RFC 8446 section 7.3](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc8446#section-7.3).  And these names are also used in the guide you used instead of the RFC, i.e. "server handshake traffic secret" can be found in "Server Handshake Keys Calc".

Comment: @SteffenUllrich Thanks- so the client and server use their secrets to find a key which they use for sending data? Why don't they both just use the same key? I still don't understand what the exporter secret is

Comment: *"I still don't understand what the exporter secret is"* - please see [RFC 8446 section 7.5](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc8446#section-7.5). In short: it is for the user of the application but not used by TLS itself. *"Why don't they both just use the same key?"* - this is a new question and should not be asked in a comment. Anyway, it is no different from previous TLS versions in this regard. And note that all these question don't really about the sslkeylogfile (your original question) but about understanding TLS itself.